# How can I determine the type of array and return either its duplicated or unique number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, numbers, integer

How can I determine the of an array (in this case, 'duplicate' or 'unique') to make it return either the duplicated or unique number. The array `arr` contains positive integers. It may be one of the following:

1. There are numbers 1 to n, only one number is duplicate (repeated two times), the other numbers are unique.
2. There are numbers 1 to n, only one number is unique, the other numbers are repeated two times.

I have attached my current code below, but since it's way too slow; I am wondering if it is possible to solve the problem in another way.

```
function duplicateOrUnique(arr) {
  var duplicate = 0,
      output = 0,
      n = 0,
      num = {}

  arr.forEach(function(item) { // Inserts every item in 'arr' to list 'num'
    num[item] = 0;
  })

  arr.forEach(function(item) { // Applies value (count) to every item list 'num'
    num[item] += 1;
  })

  arr.forEach(function(item) { // Check how many times an item have been duplicated
    if (num[item] > 1) {
      duplicate += 1;
    }
  })

  // Detertime wether 'arr' includes duplicated or unique numbers
  if (duplicate > 2) { // unique
    arr.forEach(function(item) {
      if (num[item] == 1) {
        output = item;
      }
    })
  } else { // duplicated
    arr.forEach(function(item) {
      if (num[item] >= 2) {
        output = item;
      }
    })
  }
  return output;
}
```

### Note

- All numbers are positive integers that from 1 to n.
- The length of the array will always be more than 5.

### Examples

```
[1,2,3,6,5,4,1] should return 1
[1,2,3,1,2,3,4] should return 4
[3,6,9,2,5,8,1,4,8,7] should return 8
[9,8,7,1,2,3,9,7,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6] should return 8
```

Comment: which one would you like to get, the dupes or the unique values? what is with `n+1` or `2*n-1` elements?

Comment: @NinaScholz If you're given an array where only **one number has equals**, the type of the array should be 'duplicate', Otherwise, if you're given an array where only **one is different**, the type should be 'unique'.

Comment: I realize I'm a little late to the party, but what number would you return for an array like `[1,3,1]`? This has exactly one unique and one duplicate number.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I forgot to mention this, but the length of the array should always be more than 5. Therefore, a scenario like you described would be impossible to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

```js
function duplicateOrUnique(array) {
  const unique = [...new Set(array)]
  const lookup = unique.map(function (value) {
    return this.indexOf(value) === this.lastIndexOf(value)
  }, array)
  
  return unique[
    lookup.indexOf(
      lookup.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) === 1
    )
  ]
}

console.log(
  duplicateOrUnique([1,2,3,6,5,4,1])
) // should return 1

console.log(
  duplicateOrUnique([1,2,3,1,2,3,4])
) // should return 4

console.log(
  duplicateOrUnique([3,6,9,2,5,8,1,4,8,7])
) // should return 8

console.log(
  duplicateOrUnique([9,8,7,1,2,3,9,7,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6])
) // should return 8
```

#### Explanation

```
const unique = [...new Set(array)]
```

Generates an array containing every unique value.

```
const lookup = unique.map(function (value) {
  return this.indexOf(value) === this.lastIndexOf(value)
}, array)
```

Creates a lookup table to determine if each value is unique in the original array (`true` if unique, `false` if duplicate), by testing whether its first index is equivalent to its last index.

```
lookup.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) === 1
```

Determines which type of array by summing the lookup table of booleans. If only one value in the array is unique, then the result is `true`, otherwise `false`.

```
return unique[lookup.indexOf(...)]
```

Performs a reverse-lookup of the number to return by getting the index of the desired type (unique or duplicate) based on the type of array.

Answer (score 1):

If ES6 is not a problem, you can use a couple of sets to see how many duplicates are found (pre-ES6, a hash object could be used):

```js
function duplicateOrUnique(arr) {
 const set= new Set(), dupes= new Set();     
  for(let i of arr)
   (set.has(i) ? dupes : set).add(i); //if set contains i -> add to dupes
  if(dupes.size === 1) //one duplicate
   return [...dupes][0];  //return first entry of duplicates
  return [...set].find(i => !dupes.has(i)); //one unique-> filter out all dupes from the set
}

console.log(duplicateOrUnique([1,2,3,6,5,4,1]));
console.log(duplicateOrUnique([1,2,3,1,2,3,4]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the following way

```js
function getVal(arr){
    arr.sort();
    let counUniq = 0, countDup = 0;
    let uniq = -1, dup = -1;
    for(let i=1; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] == arr[i-1]){
            countDup++;
            dup = arr[i];
        }
        else if(arr[i] != arr[i+1]) {
            counUniq++;
            uniq = arr[i];
        }
    }
    //console.log(counUniq, countDup, uniq, dup);
    if(counUniq == 1){
        return uniq;
    }
    else {
        return dup;
    }
}


console.log(getVal([1,2,3,6,5,4,1]))
console.log(getVal([1,2,3,1,2,3,4]))
console.log(getVal([3,6,9,2,5,8,1,4,8,7]))
console.log(getVal([9,8,7,1,2,3,9,7,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6]))
```

it uses sorting, and just checks which array type is it

Answer (score 0):

You could just check the set where the value belongs and then render the result for only one item.

```js
function fn(array) {
    var one = new Set,
        two = new Set;

    array.forEach(a => two.has(a) || one.has(a) && (one.delete(a), two.add(a)) || one.add(a));
    return (one.size === 1 ? one : two).values().next().value;
}

console.log(fn([1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 1]));                               // 1
console.log(fn([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4]));                               // 4
console.log(fn([3, 6, 9, 2, 5, 8, 1, 4, 8, 7]));                      // 8
console.log(fn([9, 8, 7, 1, 2, 3, 9, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6])); // 8
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Your code does only check for 'duplicates'. '[1,1,1,1,2]' returns '1, 1, 1' instead of '2'.

Answer (score 0):

A readable but not very performant solution:

```
var arr1 =  [1,2,3,6,5,4,1];
var arr2 = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4];

var duplicatedNumber = arr1.find((it, itIndex) => arr1.some((some, someIndex) => it === some && itIndex !== someIndex));
var uniqueNumber = arr2.find((it, itIndex) => !arr2.some((other, otherIndex) => it === other && itIndex !== otherIndex));

console.log("Duplicated: ", duplicatedNumber); 
console.log("Unique: ", uniqueNumber);

// To make a function that returns either the duplicated or unique number in an array:

function findUniqueOrDuplicated(arr) {
    return arr.find((it, itIndex) => arr.some((other, othersIndex) => it === other && itIndex !== othersIndex)) ||
           arr.find((it, itIndex) => !arr.some((other, othersIndex) => it === other && itIndex !== othersIndex));
}
```